Laravel Polymorphic Relation with models that have belongs to relation with another model
I have Download model that has morphTo relation with 3 other models "Test", "Video", "File"
as below:
enter image description here
each of them have a BelongsTo relation with "Lesson" model just like that:
enter image description here
when I try this query it works just fine and brings me all the Downloads with it's related downloadable models
enter image description here
yet when I try to get data this way:
enter image description here
it returns with this error: Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on null
am sure that all the "Download" records have a related downloadable model and that model have the belongsTo relation with name lesson
